# Horizon Connector Server login fail or blank page

Tags: vmware, horizon

Accessing the Horizon View 7.0 Administrator web interface displays a blank error window, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: [kb2144768](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2144768?src=vmw_so_vex)

or try view it with your domain name:
[image]